# function returns None instead of index

Tags: python, function

This code should return index of element, which is surrounded with equal sums of elements

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for elem in arr:
        i = arr.index(elem)
        if sum(arr[:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:]):
            return i
        else:
            pass
print find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])
print find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35])
```

and it returns

> 3
>
> None

instead of **None** should return **3** but it doesn't. Why??

Comment: Broken logic.  What does `i = arr.index(elem)` do?

Comment: You should remove the 'else: pass' part. This is useless

Comment: I also don't get the goal. What do you mean by even index

Comment: hint: if you want both the index and the item when iterating over a list, use `enumerate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `arr.index(elem)` always returns 1 (first index of `elem` in `arr`) if `elem` equals 10, in your second call of `find_even_index()`. So it can't work.

I suggest you the following solution, iterating directly on the indexes instead of on the values of the list:

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if sum(arr[0:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:]):
            return i
    return None

print(find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]))          # 3
print(find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35]))   # 3
```

Comment: That's suitable solution, but how to make it return -1 if there is no proper element?

Comment: Just replace `None` with `-1`. If it suits you, you can consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `arr.index(elem)` returns only the first index of `elem` in list `arr`.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]                                   
>>> lst.index(1)                                            
0                                                           
>>> lst.index(2)                                            
1                                                           
>>> lst.index(3)                                            
2
```

Use `enumerate` instead to keep track of index while iterating through list, like so:

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for i, _ in enumerate(arr):
        if sum(arr[:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:]):
            return i

print(find_even_index([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]))  # 3
print(find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35]))  # 3
```

Comment: `enumerate()` isn't even needed here, as he doesn't actually use `elem`. Just iterating over the indices is sufficient.

Comment: @glibdud ah! Yes. I usually use `enumerate` in these cases. Added a small change. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this out. it tends to work, just that I am using recursion instead of looping

```
    def func(array, i):
        if sum(array[:i]) == sum(array[i+1:]):
            return i
        else:
            a = i + 1
            return func(array, a)

    print(func([20,10,30,10,10,15,35], 0)) #produces 3 as the answer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second case is when you get to the fourth iteration and your script executes `i = arr.index(10)`. You expect this to return `3`, but `list.index()` finds the *first* instance of `10` in the list, which is in position 1. In this case, you don't actually want to iterate over the *elements* of the list, but over their indices. Try this:

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if sum(arr[:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:]):
            return i
```